# Не работает русский шрифт на хостинге

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, multilanguage

сделал заказчику сайт лендинг, проблема в том что реализовал перевод через базу данных и русские шрифты не отображаются(с английским и эстонским все в порядке), а выдает знаки вопроса(картинка ниже). Пытался играться с кодировкой в php, .htaccess, ничего не помогает хостинг Эстонский, сам я тоже из Эстонии. База у меня с кодировкой utf8_general_ci. Извиняюсь за свой русский.https://www.zone.ee/et/[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в `<meta>` указал кодировку?

Comment: [<meta charset="UTF-8">](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Comment: База это это конечно хорошо, но вот подключение php-клиента к этой базе точно тоже использует utf8?

Comment: @Antonio112009 все meta указаны

Comment: @andreymal да подключение я сейчас проверил тоже UTF-8

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/112291

Comment: @Antonio112009 Большое спасибо, применил после коннекта mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8'); и заработало

Comment: @VladiTek перенес комментарий в ответ) Приятно было Вам помочь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в ваш код `mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'кодировка')`. В вашем случае это будет `utf8`. Пример кода:

```php
$connect = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'твой_пароль', 'название_бд');
mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй прописать в html файлах кодировку,если такие есть вручную.Например:
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Попробовал не помогло(